# How can I apply the hough circle method to a thresholded image?

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform, threshold

I currently have a program that can detect colored balls with openCV and I'd like to add the HoughCircle method to make it better.

I had the idea to apply the HoughCircle method on the thresholded image that i got from the **inRange** method but unfortunately it does not work.
I saw that the HoughCircle method is only taking gray-scale images, is there a way to pass the thresholded image to it ?

this is how I do :

```cpp
int isBall(Mat threshold){
    Mat temp;
    threshold.copyTo(temp);
    std::vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(temp, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, temp.rows/8 
                                                    , 100
                                                    , 50 
                                                    , 15 /* min radius */
                                                    , 200 /* max radius */
                                                    );
    printf("nb circles = %d\n", circles.size());
    if(circles.size() > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

the thresholded image is coming from :

```cpp
inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
```

Here is an example of a thresholded image that i can get :
https://www.noelshack.com/2019-39-5-1569586501-threshold.png

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the parameters used in HoughCircles. You can use the example image just fine if you convert it to a gray-scale one.

The main culprit is `param2=50`, that is a [threshold for circle centers at detection stage](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d). If you set it to a smaller value, the algorithm will be able to return the circle.

I have tested `HoughCircles()` using `param2=10` and the result is this:

[image]